# Find and replace a matching object in an array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of people objects. When a new person is added, a function should check if someone with that name has already been added. If so, that object should be replaced with the new one. If the new person hasn't already been added then they are simply added to the end. What's the best way to do that?

Here's the object

```
    const people = [
    {name: Joe M, town: London},
    {name: Julie A, town: London},
    {name: Sally N, town: Edinburgh},
    {name: Max M, town: Liverpool}
  ]
```

Here's what I tried

```
  for(let key in people) {
  if(people[key].name === newPerson.name){
    people.splice(key, 1, newPerson)
  } else {
    this.people.push(this.newPerson)
  }
}
```

Comment: `for...in...` is for objects and not arrays

Comment: And what's the problem here?

Comment: isn't it possible there can be 2 people with same name?

Comment: I'm not actually using the name property in my application, I've just written a simplified array to illustrate my problem clearly.

Comment: The problem you had was the logic. You only want to splice or push once, instead of for each person inside the people array. As shown below, `Array.find()` and `Array.findIndex()` are both fine tools to check if the person already exists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many ways, try this:

```
  const index = people.findIndex(p => p.name === newPerson.name)

  if(index === -1) {
     people.push(newPerson);
  } else {
     people[index] = newPerson;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/), you can find mathcing index, if user will not found **indexOf** will return -1, so we can check this and do like this:

```
const index = _.indexOf(people, { name: newPerson.name});
if (index >= 0) people.splice(index, 1, newPerson)
else people.push(newPerson)
```

Also, if you dont wont to use lodash you can replace index constant with:
 `people.findIndex(i => i.name === newPerson.name);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use "find" method from Lodash library (https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#find).

You search for the person you want and, with the index, you can easily change it.